# How to call DeltaLog checkpoint() if no change since previous checkpoint was created?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, delta-lake

Could someone help me explain how deltalog checkpoints work? I'm facing a problem where I try to create regular checkpoints at a fixed interval, but if there wasn't any change on the delta table since the previous checkpoint creation I end up with the below error:

```
An error was encountered:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: State of the checkpoint doesn't match that of the snapshot.
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.Checkpoints$.writeCheckpoint(Checkpoints.scala:328)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.Checkpoints.writeCheckpointFiles(Checkpoints.scala:145)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.Checkpoints.writeCheckpointFiles$(Checkpoints.scala:144)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog.writeCheckpointFiles(DeltaLog.scala:59)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.Checkpoints.$anonfun$checkpoint$1(Checkpoints.scala:137)
  at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
  at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksLogging.recordOperation(DatabricksLogging.scala:77)
  at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksLogging.recordOperation$(DatabricksLogging.scala:67)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog.recordOperation(DeltaLog.scala:59)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLogging.scala:106)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation$(DeltaLogging.scala:91)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLog.scala:59)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.Checkpoints.checkpoint(Checkpoints.scala:133)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.Checkpoints.checkpoint$(Checkpoints.scala:132)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.delta.DeltaLog.checkpoint(DeltaLog.scala:59)
  ... 55 elided
```

Comment: Can you add the code snippet wherein a/the checkpoint(s) are created?

Comment: It's just a simple call to
DeltaLog.forTable(spark,s3Table).checkpoint()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reiterate what was stated in the Delta Users #deltalake-oss Slack channel:

- checkpoints are created automatically (by default every 10 commits) (see more [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/08/21/diving-into-delta-lake-unpacking-the-transaction-log.html))
- this makes me wonder why you are manually creating checkpoints at a fixed interval when that is already done for you
- even when old checkpoints are deleted during log cleanup, the new checkpoints still contain the entire state of the table at that point in time. So losing old checkpoints doesn't invalidate newer data.